# Problem with database row and column selection <sqlite3.Row object at 0x000001DE5B746D50> getting this wierd return

Tags: python, sqlite

hii when i was trying to do a project on database management using sqlite i face this problem. the code is

```
import sqlite3
class DBConnect():
    def __init__(self):
        self.db=sqlite3.connect("Registrations.db")
        self.db.row_factory=sqlite3.Row
        self.db.execute("create table if not exists Ticket(ID integer Primary key autoincrement,name text,gender text,comment text)")
        self.db.commit()
    def Add(self,Name,gender,comment):
        self.db.row_factory=sqlite3.Row
        self.db.execute("insert into Ticket(name,gender,comment) values(?,?,?)",(Name,gender,comment))
        self.db.commit()
        return "DATA ADDED SUCCESFULLY"
    def Show(self):
        self.db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
        cursor=self.db.execute("select * from Ticket").fetchall()
        print(type(cursor))
        return cursor
```

Iam not getting any row data instead i get the address where it is stored like this <sqlite3.Row object at 0x000001DE5B746D50>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No errors but not getting an expected output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64330984/no-errors-but-not-getting-an-expected-output)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to print the contents of the row i.e `Name Gender etc` but instead ended up printing the type of the object `print(type(cursor))` which is `<sqlite3.Row object at 0x000001DE5B746D50>`.

To print the contents of the row you can try `print(cursor)`

Comment: I'd loop through the cursor `for row in cursor:` because that would give the opportunity for more precise pretty-printing. YMMV.

Comment: No thats not the issue.<sqlite3.Row object at 0x000001DE5B746D50>. this is seen ony when i try to print the row details.when i print  type(cursor ) iam getting <class 'list'>